# Use setInterval in the fucntion and pass parameters in it

Tags: jquery, parameters, intervals

I want to use setInterval in the function and pass parameters in it. Here I am calling the red_orange_on variable and pass parameters in it and this parameter assign to the setInterval function. Please tell me it's the right way which I want to do. If any other way to do this please tell me.

Here is my code.

```
function red_orange_light(road_side) {
     $(road_side + ' .orange').css('opacity', 1);
}

var road_side;
var red_orange_on = function (road_side) {
    setInterval(function () {
       red_orange_light(road_side);
    }, 4000);
};

function signal_1() {
    red_orange_on(".road-1");
}

signal_1();
```

Comment: could you can put when is called red_orang_on?

Answer (score 1):

you can pass your value at the third parameter of setInterval.

```js
function red_orange_light(road_side) {
  alert(road_side);
}

var road_side;
var red_orange_on = function(road_side) {
  setInterval(red_orange_light, 4000, road_side);
};

function signal_1() {
  red_orange_on(".road-1");
}

signal_1();
```